# how to make a better code of these nested-if conditions

Tags: perl, coding-style, nested-if

I have a nested-if code like this

```
 if (condition1 or condition2 or condition3 ) {
           if  (condition1) {
           }
           elsif (condition2) {
           }
           elsif (condition3) {
           }
 }
```

Now obviously, conditions(1,2 and 3) are already checked on outer `if`, so I don't want them to be checked again in inner `if-elsif` statements.
So my solution was, removing the outer `if` totally. But again this will make it go through `if-elsif`.

So what if there are like 10-15 conditions. Which one is better? Or Is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer `if` is unneccessary.

Besides that, only three possible optimizations seem reasonable:

1. profile the code before optimizing, and sort the if/else conditions so that the most common condition is tested first etc.
2. Use a data structure to represent the conditions. Should you be testing for some sort of equality (`if ($foo eq $bar){...}elsif($foo eq $baz){...}`), then a hash can transform the lookup from linear to constant time:

   ```
   %hash = ($bar => sub{...}, $baz => sub{...});
   my $code = $hash{$foo} or do{"this is the trailing else"};
   $code->(); # execute the coderef
   ```

   This is wildly flexible, but includes the indirection of closures.
3. If you have to re-check a condition, cache the result. The scope of a variable that was declared in a condition reaches into all subsequent conditions and blocks of the if/else chain:

   ```
   if ( my $cond1 = ... and ...) {
     ...
   } elsif ($cond1 and my $cond2 = ...) {
     ...
   } elsif ($cond2) {
     ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Hash is my choice for many `if` conditions, with conditions being equality.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how often your code is being executed. With complicated sets of if-statements, it's better to optimise for readability, since compared to most other operations they're cheap. However, in your example above, I would remove the outer statement altogether, it's simply unnecessary. Perl optimises code while it parses it anyway.

Comment: That was good about perl optimization. I better remove outer if then and use hash if possible for multiple ifs

Answer (score 2):

If your conditions are all tests on the value of the same variable, you can use `given`/`when` in Perl 5.10.1 and later:

```
use 5.010;

given ($foo) {
  when ('bar') { ... }                  # string literal
  when (4) { ... }                      # numeric literal
  when (qw[ xyzzy plugh ]) { ... }      # any of multiple literals
  when (/^whee+$/) { ... }              # regex match
  default { ... }                       # fallthrough if nothing matched
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I had not known about this before.

Comment: Beware of using this construct as there is talk of removing it. It relies on the smart-match operator `~~` which has shortcomings.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps the Switch control sentence may have sense in your code (in depends on the conditions you are checking). Take a look at the [documentation of Switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html).

**Update**
Starting with the 5.10 perl release, there is a [given/when control flow](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements).

```
 use feature "switch";
```

Comment: It's above 5.10? I will have to check that. I did found it though.

Comment: The Switch module is deprecated. The `given/when` feature is the replacement, `use feature 'switch'`.

Comment: I checked and for reasons of Source Filtering(a module which affects the way in which a file use-ing it will be parsed. They are commonly used to simulate syntactical features which Perl does not have natively ), switch case is no longer used. `given/when` is the replacement

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the outer `if` statements because all the conditions will be checked anyway by the inner `if` statements.
2. If you arrange which `if` conditions according to priority as in condition1 is more important than condition2, then of course, you can't change the order of the checks.
3. If you arrange which `if` conditions according to frequency of occurrence, then you can rearrange based on frequency, as you test or profile the program.
4. If condition1 is true, then run statement1. If your statements are too long, then put them into subroutines and call them, so it would look neater.

   ```
   if    (condition1) {&run_statement1();}
   elsif (condition2) {&run_statement2();}
   elsif (condition3) {&run_statement3();}
   elsif (condition4) {&run_statement4();}
   elsif (condition5) {&run_statement5();}
   elsif (condition6) {&run_statement6();}
   elsif (condition7) {&run_statement7();}
   else               {&run_elsestatement();}
   ```
5. Don't unnecessarily complicate or obfuscate the code. Keep it simple, readable and fulfilling your objectives.

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
(condition1) ? run_statement1() :
(condition2) ? run_statement2() :
(condition3) ? run_statement3() : run_elsestatement() ;
```

I'm a fan of less typing.  Another option, if your evaluated conditions produce 'unique' results, is to use the result as a key in a hash-of-functions.  This removes the conditional checking above completely.

For instance, if the conditions were based on the value held in a scalar called '$var', then you could simply use those different values as the keys to the hash.

```
$conditionalFunctionHash{$var}->();
```